# On Yosemite, how can I audit the safety of an executable?

Tags: macos, security, sandbox

I would like to audit an executable binary from an untrusted source, and ultimately maintain whether it is safe to run it.
My main interest is to establish, in a *safe* fashion, whether said binary tries to manipulate system resources, do some sort of privilege escalation or modify anything else which might compromise integrity or safety of the system.

I have looked into [sandbox-exec](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sandbox-exec.1.html) but could not find any current documentation on the available options.

- What is a good and reliable method of establishing that an executable is safe?
- Is `sandbox-exec` the right tool?
- Is there a place which offers up to date and comprehensive documentation on OSX sandboxing?
- What could be alternative strategies?

Comment: You can't tell it might run OK for the first 100 times and then do something untoward - for sandboxing see https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/ however you can't be certain the app was written to fully use this unless it is from the Mac App Store

Comment: This is why I am asking if a methodology exists to audit a binary, e.g. by restrictevely sandboxing it.

Comment: @Mark actually your link documents how to achieve  sandboxing when creating your own app. I am rather interested in sandboxing an existing binary though.

Comment: Is this application a communicating one? Either internally toward local servers or externally through IP.

Comment: No. It should not need (nor would I want to grant it) network access. I am not sure about IPC sockets though. But I would rather restrict access to those as well.

Comment: Also, I expect the application does not need to write to the fs (except maybe for /tmp), but I would like to grant it unrestricted reading access to the system.